# When is a quantum state stationary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

If a quantum state is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, then it is stationary. But can a state be stationary if it is not an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian? If yes, how can one prove whether a state is stationary?

Comment: Stationary states are _defined_ to be eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. So your question is saying "If A, then A. But can we have A, if not A?"

Comment: @knzhou I thought so, but in [another question I asked](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268433/linear-combination-of-eigenstates-problem/268573#268573), someone told me "So the state is stationary if it is an eigenstate. But this is not the only possibility for stationarity." so I'm in doubt now.

Comment: That answer is wrong, in several places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A state $\Psi(x,t)$ is stationary if

$$\mid\Psi(x,t)\mid^2=\mid\Psi(x,0)\mid^2$$

This means that the time dependence of $\Psi(x,t)$ must be in the form

$$\Psi(x, t) =  \Psi(x, 0) \ e^{i \phi t}$$

but you also have (Schrödinger's equation)

$$i \hbar \partial_t \ \Psi(x,t) =\hat H \ \Psi(x,t)$$

so that we obtain

$$(i \hbar)(i \phi) \Psi(x,t) =\hat H \ \Psi(x,t) \\ \to-\hbar \phi \Psi(x,t) =\hat H \ \Psi(x,t)$$

i.e. $\Psi(x,t)$ is an eigenstate of $\hat H$ with eigenvalue $-\hbar \phi$. This means, incidentally, that $\phi$ must have the dimensions of energy/action, that is to say

$$\phi=\frac E \hbar$$

So if a state is stationary, it is an eigenstate of $\hat H$. Since we know that the reverse is true, we can conclude that a state is stationary *if and only if* it is an eigenstate of $\hat H$.

Comment: You're answer is good but you might want to add *why* $\Psi(x, t) =  \Psi(x, 0) \ e^{i \phi t}$ is true. Don't assume people know that.

Comment: Yeah, you pretty much used circular reasoning. From $|\Psi(x,t)|^2=|\Psi(x,0)|^2$ immediately comes only that $\Psi(x,t)=e^{i\alpha(x,t)}\Psi(x,0)$. Why it should be just a $\phi t$ demands proof... I'm going to present short proof I've made up now in my answer though I'm sure there may be much more elegant way.

Comment: Arr, no, I've stupid mistake, so I'll hide that for now