# What is the definition of a stationary state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, definition, quantum-states

In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/268974), a state, $\psi(t)$ is said to be stationary if

$$
\begin{equation*}
|\psi(t)|^2=|\psi(0)|^2.
\end{equation*}
$$

That answer then concludes that a state can only be stationary if it is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian.

But, I believe it's possible to satisfy $|\psi(t)|^2=|\psi(0)|^2$ for a state that is not a Hamiltonian eigenstate. Consider, for example, the state $|\psi(t)\rangle=\sum_j \alpha_j(0)e^{-iE_jt/\hbar}|j\rangle$. In this case,

$$
\begin{align*}
  |\psi(t)|^2 &= \langle\psi(t)|\psi(t)\rangle,\\
  &= \left(\sum_k \alpha_k^*(0) e^{iE_kt/\hbar}\langle k|\right)
     \left(\sum_j \alpha_j(0) e^{-iE_jt/\hbar}|j\rangle\right),\\
  &= \sum_{j,k} \alpha_k^*(0) \alpha_j(0) \exp[i(E_k-E_j)t/\hbar] \langle k|j\rangle,\\
  &= \sum_{j,k} \alpha_k^*(0) \alpha_j(0) \exp[i(E_k-E_j)t/\hbar] \delta_{jk},\\
  &= \sum_j \alpha_j^*(0) \alpha_j(0) \exp[i(E_j-E_j)t/\hbar],\\
  &= \sum_j |\alpha_j(0)|^2,\\
  &= |\psi(0)|^2.
\end{align*}
$$

So, if we use $|\psi(t)|^2=|\psi(0)|^2$ as the definition of a stationary state, wouldn't it also be possible for a stationary state to be a superposition of Hamiltonian eigenstates? However, [this other answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/211046) says that a superposition of stationary states is not a stationary state.

Which is correct? It seems to me like this comes down to how stationary state is defined (unless, of course, I made a mistake in my proof). If so, what's the definition of a [stationary state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_state)?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a muddle of notation here.

If
$$
| \psi(t) \rangle
$$
is a quantum state then one might define the notation
$$
| \psi(t) |^2 \equiv \langle \psi(t) | \psi(t) \rangle . \tag{1}
$$

On the other hand, if $\psi(x,y,z,t)$ is a wavefunction then one might define the notation
$$
|\psi(t)|^2
$$
as a shorthand for
$$
|\psi(x,y,z,t)|^2  . \tag{2}
$$

For a normalized state, version (1) will give 1 no matter how the state evolves, while version (2) will give the modulus-squared wavefunction which can change with time.

To relate the wavefunction to the Dirac notation, use
$$
\psi(x,y,z,t) = \langle (x,y,z) | \psi(t) \rangle
$$
where the bra part of the bracket on the right refers to an eigenstate of position.

Comment: In the original Dirac's notation, the bra would be written as $< x,y,z |$, without parentheses.